# Excel cell value editing when VBA program running

Tags: excel, vba

When Excel VBA macro excecuting, can we change values of cell in excel in which program is running?
Editing option i want to enable when script/program is running

Comment: This calls for security issues and data incoherency. I guess you should avoid editing of the sheet while your program is running.

Comment: If your macro is "running" (like a big batch job) then the workbook typically becomes non-responsive so I dont think you would be able to. Give it a go?

Comment: You cannot do nothing while macro is executing. Why not edit your macro?

Answer (score 0):

When your VBA consists of a lot of loops you can still do things in excel by adding:

```
DoEvents
```

Add this inside the loop(s), this will allow for other events (such as the user changing stuff) to happen while the program runs.

Do keep in mind the warnings others already gave you, you can seriously disrupt your VBA script, because the user could actually mess with all the excel spreadsheet content that you might interact with in your script.

A little "fun" example:

```
Option Explicit

Sub example_DoEvents()
    Dim timer1 As Date

    timer1 = Now()

    Do While Now() < timer1 + 10 / 60 / 60 / 24 'only let it last for 10 seconds
        DoEvents
        ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value2 = Selection.Address
    Loop

    MsgBox "END"

End Sub
```